# Is there a file that always exists and a 'normal' user can't lstat it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I need this for a unit test. There's a function that does [lstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) on the file path passed as its parameter. I have to trigger the code path where the `lstat` fails (because the code coverage has to reach 90%)

The test can run only under a single user, therefore I was wondering if there's a file in Ubuntu that always exists, but normal users have no read access to it, or to its folder. (So `lstat` would fail on it unless executed as root.)

A non-existent file is not a solution, because there's a separate code path for that, which I'm already triggering.

EDIT: Lack of read access to the file only is not enough. With that `lstat` can still be executed. I was able to trigger it (on my local machine, where I have root access), by creating a folder in /root, and a file in it. And setting permission 700 on the folder. So I'm searching for a file that is in a folder that is only accessible by root.

Comment: IMHO `/etc/shadow`

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks. Maybe my question is wrong. That file is readable, but I can lstat it. Then its directory has to be non-readable?

Comment: You cannot assume the existence of any file, because your program may run in a chroot or separate namespace. If assuming that /proc is mounted is OK and init is nothing special, then `/proc/1/fd/0` should do.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks that works on my local machine. Hmm then I'll try it on the QA and Staging pool too.

Comment: Why are you tying your test code to a particular flavor of OS when you could just *create* a throwaway file and remove your own read access to it?

Comment: I'd argue that it's not really a *unit* test once it starts depending on a real, rather than mocked, filesystem.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I allow unit tests to scribble on ${TMP:/tmp}/$$ at will.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On modern Linux systems, you should be able to use `/proc/1/fdinfo/0` (information for the file descriptor 1 (stdout) of the process of id 1 (`init` in the root pid namespace which should be running as `root`)).

You can find a list with (as a normal user):

```
sudo find /etc /dev /sys /proc -type f -print0 |
  perl -l -0ne 'print unless lstat'
```

(remove `-type f` if you don't want to restrict to regular files).

`/var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache` is another potential candidate if you only need  to  consider Ubuntu systems. It should work on most GNU systems as `/var/cache/ldconfig` is created read+write+searchable to root only by the `ldconfig` command that comes with the GNU libc.

Comment: Thanks! If `/proc/1/fdinfo/0` works on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, that's more than enough.

Comment: Using `/proc/1/fdinfo/0` does not necessarily work in a container (e.g., a Docker container), and often unit tests are run in such containers in CI.

Comment: @PhilippWendler, I did mention _the root pid namespace_ already. The OP is not asking about containers but about files guaranteed to be there in the filesystem layout of a Ubuntu system. As containers could contain any file and directory layout, that question could not be answerable there.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the [lstat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) man page you can get some inspiration on cases that might make it fail with errors other than ENOENT (file does not exist.)

The most obvious one is:

> **EACCES**
>   Search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of *path*.

So you need a directory you can't search from.

Yes, you can look for one that's already in your system (perhaps `/var/lib/private` if it exists?) But you might as well create one yourself, with the equivalent of:

```
$ mkdir myprivatedir
$ touch myprivatedir/myunreachablefile
$ chmod 0 myprivatedir
$ ls -l myprivatedir/myunreachablefile
```

The lstat(2) operation will fail with EACCES here. (Removing all permissions from the directory ensures that. Maybe you don't even need that much and `chmod -x` removing execute permissions would be enough, since execute permissions on a directory are needed to access files under it.)

There's another creative way to make lstat(2) fail, looking at its man page:

> **ENOTDIR**
>   A component of the path prefix of *path* is not a directory.

So, trying to access a file such as `/etc/passwd/nonexistent` should trigger this error, which again is different from ENOENT ("No such file or directory") and might suit your needs.

Another one is:

> **ENAMETOOLONG**
>   *path* is too long.

But you might need a really long name for this one (I believe 4,096 bytes is the typical limit, but your system/filesystem might have a longer one.)

Finally, it's hard to tell whether any of these will be *actually* useful for you. You say you want something that doesn't trigger the "file doesn't exist" scenario. While typically that means an ENOENT error, in practice many higher-level checks will simply interpret any errors from lstat(2) as "does not exist". For example `test -e` or the equivalent `[ -e ...]` from the shell might simply just interpret all of the above as "does not exist", especially since it doesn't have a good way to return a different error message and not returning an error would imply the file exists, which is most certainly not the case.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Great point! Updated.

Answer (score 6):

You can `find` it yourself.

Using `/etc` -- the configuration files directory as a starting point:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -perm 0400 -user root
```

On my system, this does not return anything.

You can be a less restrictive and allow group `root` (only user `root` should be a member of group `root`), and a look out for a permission of `440`:

```
sudo find /etc -perm 0440 -user root -group root
```

On my system this returns:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/README
/etc/sudoers
```

---

**Edit:**

Based on your edit, you're looking for a directory that does not have sufficient permission for the invoking user to prevent directory listing:

```
sudo find / -perm o-rwx -type d -user root -group root
```

here I'm looking for directories (`-type d`) that lack the read-write-execute perm bits for others (`o-rwx`) and is owned by `root:root`.

Technically, just the absense of execute (`x`) bit would prevent a directory listing (`lstat(2)`) on directory.

In the output I've found `/run/systemd/inaccessible/` on my Systemd init based system.

**Regarding files in `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`:**

- These filesystems are virtual FS i.e. they reside on memory, not on disk
- If you plan to rely on `/proc`, use `/proc/1/` i.e. rely on something under PID 1, not any later PIDs to have reliability/consistency as the later PIDs (processes) are not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Thanks, I think my question is wrong. I can still lstat files without read access to them. Maybe the access to the folder has to be limited? (I modified the title)

Comment: Thanks. With `find / -type d -perm 0400 -user root` I have found the directory `/proc/20/map_files/`, if I refer to a made-up file name inside that folder, like `/proc/20/map_files/asdasd`, then it always fails. Does that folder always exist on Ubuntu?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten, the directories in `/proc/1/` might be safer, since init always exists. But that's `proc`, not a regular filesystem, in case it matters.

Comment: Thanks I gave an upvote, but accepted the other answer, because he said it is guaranteed that `/proc/1/fdinfo/0` works on modern Ubuntus.

Comment: `-perm o-rwx` is like `-perm 0`, bits are all off to start with. Here, you'd want `! -perm -1`.